# Height and Width of Player Depth View using Kinect SDK

Tags: c#, kinect

This code shows that how we can find the player from the depth Image:

```
this.depthData = new short[frame.PixelDataLength];

frame.CopyPixelDataTo(this.depthData);

    for (int depthIndex = 0; depthIndex < depthData.Length; depthIndex++)
    {
            player = depthData[depthIndex] & DepthImageFrame.PlayerIndexBitmask;
    }
```

I wanna ask about how can I find Width and Height of Depth View of the player ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link will give you a starting point.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/380152/Kinect-for-Windows-Find-User-Height-Accurately

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. Can you please outline the main points in a dedicated answer here. Thank you.